what does it mean by 'size must be two numbers' I get this error when trying to blit an image into my window in pygame
when trying to blit an image into my window, I get the error code
TypeError: size must be two numbers

I am trying to scale my pixel art without It being blurry so I am trying to use the function smoothscale, but when trying to run it, it displayes this error code, here is the code
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.idle_D_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('Art_Assets/Idle/Knight_Idle_Sprite0.png').convert_alpha(), PLAYER_SIZE)
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(PLAYER_START_X, PLAYER_START_Y)
        self.speed = PLAYER_SPEED

idk if this is an easy fix or not as I am new to programming in general, and thought trying to make a game would be a more fun way to learn.
thank you :)

Look at the pygame.transform documentation:

pygame.transform.smoothscale() scale a surface to an arbitrary size smoothly
[..snipped..]
The size is a 2 number sequence for (width, height).

If you check their linked examples, you see that your code should be more like
pygame.transform.smoothscale(texture, (PLAYER_SIZE, PLAYER_SIZE))

assuming you want to scale it to a square. Otherwise, do size=(width, height)
